# Value on the cut

Tags: complex

I did the following evaluation

```
(-x)^-a /. {x -> 1.23 , a -> 2.34}
```

> 0.296789 - 0.539856 I

Now I tried to play around it a bit and did the same evaluation in the following manner

```
(-(1/x))^a /. {x -> 1.23, a -> 2.34}
```

> 0.296789 + 0.539856 I

Now here is where the confusion starts. Both the values are the same except that there is a sign change in the imaginary part of both the values which leads to an ambiguity as to which value is correct and why? Further digging it is evident that I am trying to find the value on the cut of the above function. So why is there a change in the sign in both the evaluations?And more importantly how to resolve the ambiguity in the answers?

Comment: Have you had a course in complex analysis? It it not so easy to explain.  Consider what happens when you invert each process: for instance the first one ``(0.29678850402670853` - 0.5398562846952311` I)^(-1/a) /. a -> 2.34`` does not give `1.23`.  The two answers are related by a factor of $e^{2\pi i a}$: ``((0.29678850402670853` - 0.5398562846952311` I) Exp[
    2 Pi I a Range[0, 1]]) /. a -> 2.34``.  You can extend the `Range[]` to get other branch values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mathematica doesn't think the two expressions are equal:

```
PowerExpand[(-x)^-a, Assumptions->x>0]
PowerExpand[(-1/x)^a, Assumptions->x>0]
```

> E^(-I a π) x^-a

> E^(I a π) x^-a

So, for real but non-even-integer `a`, the two expressions are complex conjugates of each other.

Perhaps a more compelling example is to take $x=1$ and $a=1/2$

```
(-1)^(-1/2)
(-1)^(1/2)
```

> -I

> I

Comment: When you say MATHEMATICA doesn't think that  the two expressions are equal this implies that they are indeed equal it's just with MATHEMATICA that they are treated differently ??

Comment: @Erosannin No, I don't think they are equal. See edit.

Comment: okay so does this implies that I am not allowed to do this naive inversion while dealing with complex functions?

Comment: @Erosannin Correct. You can do `(-x)^(-a)` -> `1/(-x)^a`, but not what you tried.

Answer (score 1):

To get a nice idea of the differences between both have a `ContourPlot` of both:

```
Row[{ContourPlot[Re[(-x)^-a], {x, 0, 2}, {a, 0, 3}], 
  ContourPlot[Im[(-x)^-a], {x, 0, 2}, {a, 0, 3}]}]
```

[image: ContourPlot of (-x)^-a]

```
Row[{ContourPlot[Re[((1/(-x)))^a], {x, 0, 2}, {a, 0, 3}], 
  ContourPlot[Im[((1/(-x)))^a], {x, 0, 2}, {a, 0, 3}]}]
```

[image: ContourPlot of ((1/(-x)))^a]

The real parts are evidently equal, but the imaginary parts are not.

```
Row[{ContourPlot[Im[(-x)^-a], {x, 0, 2}, {a, 0, 3}, 
   Epilog -> {PointSize[Medium], Point[{1.23, 2.34}]}], 
  ContourPlot[Im[((1/(-x)))^a], {x, 0, 2}, {a, 0, 3}, 
   Epilog -> {PointSize[Medium], Point[{1.23, 2.34}]}]}]
```

[image: the point of the question on the imaginary ContourPlots]